# How do i initialize a binary tree in c#

Tags: c#, binary-tree

**Can someone please tell me what i need to put in place of the '//code missing here'?**

Where i have put "code missing" is where i am stuck. I am not sure what i need to put in place. I am new to binary trees so unfortunately am not very experienced with how they work. For my assignment this is the format my teacher wants so other tutorials online have not been particularly useful

```
using System;

public class Program
{

public class binarytree

{
    public class node
    { // Single element of tree (node)
        public string data;
        public node //CODE MISSING HERE
        public node rightPointer;
    }

    public node root;

    public bool add(string item)
    {
        try //in case of memory overflow (full)
        {
            // store new item in memory and start looking from root of tree
            node newNode = new node();
            newNode.data = item;
            newNode.//CODE MISSING HERE
            newNode.rightPointer = //CODE MISSING HERE
            node currentNode = root;
            //Case that tree is empty
            if (currentNode == null)
            {
                root = newNode;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //work out where to put new item, by traversing tree until we find a left
                node previous = currentNode;
                while (currentNode != null)
                {
                    previous = currentNode;
                    //compareTo compares two strings, returns val <0 if lower
                    if (item.CompareTo(currentNode.data) //CODE MISSING HERE
                    {
                        currentNode = //CODE MISSING HERE
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentNode = currentNode.rightPointer;
                    }
                }
                if (item.CompareTo(previous.data)<0)
                {
                    //CODE MISSING HERE
                }
                else
                {
                    previous.rightPointer = newNode;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    binarytree bt = new binarytree();
    bt.add("I am root");
    bt.add("Avengers");
    bt.add("Marvel");
    Console.WriteLine(bt.root.data);
    Console.WriteLine(bt.root.//CODE MISSING HERE
    Console.WriteLine(bt.root.rightPointer.data);
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to think about how you are organizing the nodes in your tree. For example, if you've got a root node and you add a new value should it go to the left, or right?

Comment: @Sean As i understand it , please correct me if i am wrong, when you have left and right nodes these are child nodes of a parent and the value of the parent decides whether the new value should go left (if its value is lower than the parent node) and right (if the value is higher than the parent node)

Comment: Yes, storing and ordering data is a common binary tree use case. You need to thing about rebalancing the tree when items are added. For example, if you add `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` then your tree would end up with a root of `1` and all the items going to the right (in effect a linked list). You need to rebalance so `3` ends up as the root.

Comment: @Sean Ok that makes sense. So when first starting it above i should declare both a left and right pointer? after this when setting them as new nodes what should i set their value to ? would it be null?

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it

```
using System;
```

public class Program
{

```
public class binarytree
{
    public class node
    { // Single element of tree (node)
        public string data;
        public node leftPointer; 
        public node rightPointer;
    }

    public node root;

    public bool add(string item)
    {
        try //in case of memory overflow (full)
        {
            // store new item in memory and start looking from root of tree
            node newNode = new node();
            newNode.data = item;
            newNode.leftPointer = null;
            newNode.rightPointer = null; 
            node currentNode = root;
            //Case that tree is empty
            if (currentNode == null)
            {
                root = newNode;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //work out where to put new item, by traversing tree until we find a left
                node previous = currentNode;
                while (currentNode != null)
                {
                    previous = currentNode;
                    //compareTo compares two strings, returns val <0 if lower
                    if (item.CompareTo(currentNode.data)<0) 
                    {
                        currentNode = currentNode.leftPointer;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentNode = currentNode.rightPointer;
                    }
                }
                if (item.CompareTo(previous.data)<0)
                {
                    previous.leftPointer = newNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    previous.rightPointer = newNode;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    binarytree bt = new binarytree();
    bt.add("I am root");
    bt.add("Avengers");
    bt.add("Marvel");
    Console.WriteLine(bt.root.data);
    Console.WriteLine(bt.root.leftPointer.data); 
    Console.WriteLine(bt.root.rightPointer.data);
}
```

}